# SQL CLR Function to return nullable boolean

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nullable, sqlclr

I'm trying to write a SQLCLR function that will return a nullable boolean value. If I declare the function like this: `public static SqlBoolean? IsTimeZoneDST(SqlString timeZone)` then I get an error when attempting to use the assembly saying the types for the return value do not match. Is there something I am missing or is it not possible to return a nullable boolean in this instance?

Comment: `SqlBoolean` already has the ability to be "null" which can be determined with the [`SqlBoolean.IsNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlboolean.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: How are you attempting to use the assembly - post the code that throws the error, and the exact error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the .NET `Sql*` types have a `.Null` field (static property) that creates a new instance of what will be considered a `NULL` value for that datatype within T-SQL.

Also, there are several other common properties and methods of all of the `Sql*` types:

- `.IsNull` to test if the value is `NULL` as far as T-SQL is concerned
- `.Value` will return the equivalent .NET datatype, such as a `String` for `SqlString`, or `int` / `Int32` for `SqlInt32`, etc.

The only time that you should need to use a .NET nullable type, I believe, is when using the T-SQL `DATETIME2` datatype, which maps to either `DateTime` or `DateTime?`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks juharr. I knew I'd be missing something simple. The answer in case anyone else needs it is to change the declaration to: `public static SqlBoolean IsTimeZoneDST(SqlString timeZone)` and then when you need it `return SqlBoolean.Null`