# Unable to create SQL function for Regex use

Tags: sql-server, function

I am trying to create below function with External Name I am unable to create that. What is missing and below? I even called the Assembly for RegexExpressions.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsRegExMatch](@Pattern [nvarchar](4000), @Input [nvarchar](max), @Options [int])
RETURNS [bit] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [RegexExpressions].[UserDefinedFunctions].[IsRegExMatch]
```

> Error:  CREATE FUNCTION for "RegExMatches" failed because T-SQL and
>   CLR types for return value do not match.

I am trying to do this in my local SQL Server. The version is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057115)

**How can I solve this issue?**

Comment: The error seems to be telling you the problem here. the CLR isn't returning a `bit`, but your function is trying to return one. We can't see your CLR function, so there's little more we can help you with on that.

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906337/sql-clr-function-to-return-nullable-boolean My guess is your CLR is a returning a bool. But the mapping to the bit datatype is to use SqlBoolean

Comment: I know it says that "CLR isn't returning a bit" but how do I solve? I tried this as well. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906337/sql-clr-function-to-return-nullable-boolean)